# A Problem on Second Order Homogeneous Linear DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem-$1$:**

Let $P$ and $Q$ be continuous real valued functions defined on $[-1,1]$.

Let $u_i:[-1,1]\to \Bbb R$ for $i=1,2$ be the solutions of the ODE,

$$u''(x)+P(x)u'(x)+Q(x)u(x)=0\;\;,x\in[-1,1]$$

satisfying $u_1\ge0,u_2\le0$.

Let $W$ denote the Wronskian of $u_1 $ and $u_2$, then

(**A**) $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly independent.

(**B**) $u_1$ and $u_2$ are linearly dependent.

(**C**) $W(x)=0$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$

(**D**) $W(x)\ne0$ for some $x\in[-1,1]$

**My Attempt:** I tried evaluating the wronskian at $0$,
$$W(0)=u_1(0)u_2'(0)-u_2(0)u_1'(0)$$

Since $u_1\ge0,u_2\le0$, I know that  $u_1(0)\ge0$ and  $-u_2(0)\ge0$.

I cannot proceed any further as I dont know how to deal with  $u_1'(0)$ and $u_2'(0)$.

==================================================================

**Problem-$2$:**

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two linearly independent solutions of $$y''+(\sin x)y\;\;,0\le x\le1$$

Let $g(x)$ be the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$. 
Then,

(**A**) $g'>0 $ on $[0,1]$

(**B**) $g'<0 $ on $[0,1]$

(**C**) $g' $ vanishes only at one point of $[0,1]$

(**D**) $g' $ vanishes at all points of $[0,1]$

**My Attempt:**

By Abel's formula we have, $$g(x)=Ae^{-\int 0 dx}=A\;\;\;$$ which a constant.

Thus, $g'(x)=0\;\;,\forall x\in[-1,1]$. So option (**D**) must be correct.

==================================================================

For **Problem-$1$**, I don't know if I can attack the problem using some other technique. So I need some hints.

And is my solution to **Problem-$2$** correct?